# Loop over an array of UIButtons in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uibutton, nsarray, layer

I have an array of buttons which I want to change some properties in all of them.

The array is like this:

```
NSArray *buttons = @[_smallButton, _mediumButton, _largeButton, _xlargeButton];
```

The buttons are outlets:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *smallButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *mediumButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *largeButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *xlargeButton;
```

Now I want to change all `borderColor`s and set tag for each in a loop over the array:

```
for(int i=0; i< buttons.count; i++) {
   [buttons[i] layer].borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
   [buttons[i] setTag:i];
}
```

The point is that the `setTag` works fine and gets applied to all buttons but the `borderColor` is only changed for the first item, not all of them.

[image: borderColor only gets applied to the first button]

Does anybody know what I've missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set a `borderWidth` and a `cornerRadius` to all of them, i.e.:

```
for(int i=0; i< buttons.count; i++) {
   [buttons[i] layer].borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
   [buttons[i] layer].borderWidth = 1;
   [buttons[i] layer].cornerRadius = 4;
   [buttons[i] setTag:i];
}
```

Comment: Oh, Such an awful mistake, the problem was borderWidth, I set the first button borderWidth in storyboard and forgot to set the rest, thanks.